# BabylonJS : How to atach a cube to the camera?

Tags: camera, cube, babylonjs

I'm using [BabylonJS](http://www.babylonjs.com/) to make a small game and i wan't to atach a block to my camera.
The code is :

```
block.parent = camera;
```

It's working, but now i wan't the block to follow my camera with a difference of 5 pixels on the X axe for exemple.
How can i add 5 pixels ton the X axe ?
This code don't work :

```
block.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(5, 0, 0);
block.parent = camera;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you submitted should be working. 
You set the position relative to the parent object and then attach it to the parent.

You can see a live example here - http://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#2BOTII . The ground's position is the camera's position + the relative position.

If you set the ground's position to 0 you won't see the ground, as it is exactly at the camera's viewing height.

Comment: Don't works, i'm making a face (BABYLON.Mesh.CreatePlane(x+" "+y+" "+z, 1, s);face.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(this.x,this.y+0.5,this.z+0.5)) and it's working i see it. But when i'm writing this : face.parent = camera;, it's diapear and if a console.log the position, it don't move.

Comment: My guess is that it doesn't disappear, it is simply out of the camera's viewport. Try the playground (the URL i pasted) and create your own and show me here how it is not working. And try setting the Z a bit further away from the camera.

Comment: Thanks but i tryed to console.log() the mesh position that disappeared, and it's stay the same when i move :/

Comment: of course, its position is relative to his parent and will always stay the same, unless you directly change it. try mesh.getAbsolutePosition() and you will see the difference.